# How to display the exact time on php using timezone name?

Tags: php

My timezone name is :America/Belem
I need this time,

https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ScBlVdS6GLTv8weE8YH4BQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=Bel%C3%A9m+time
 My code is

```
$MNTTZ = new DateTimeZone('America/Belem');
 $dt = new DateTime("now", $MNTTZ);
                    $minutes = $dt->format('i');
                    $dayhour = $dt->format('H');
                    $hour = $dt->format('h');
                    $ampm = $dayhour >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
                    //$min =  $minutes < 10 ? '0'.$minutes : $minutes;
                    $strTime = $hour . ':' . $minutes . ' ' . $ampm;
```

Comment: Why not just use the DateTime object's `format()` method to format the time?

Comment: We need a particular city local time. So i used like above. Here i have city timezone name(America/Belem) only in my db. That's why. In my above code execution i received 1 hour difference compare with google.

Comment: No! I mean you have 5 lines of code there, extracting hours, minutes, working out AM/PM, etc...... `format()` can do that for you in one simple method call

Comment: could you please simplify the code? I  need exact time in final. Please!

Comment: Please check here https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ScBlVdS6GLTv8weE8YH4BQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=Bel%C3%A9m+time
 And execute below code also. You'll get one hour difference. check it. I need exact timezone!

Answer (score 3):

```
$timezone="America/Belem";
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
$date = new DateTime($datetime, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));
```

After this, you can change the date in whatever format you want.

```
E.g: $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

Comment: Please check here https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ScBlVdS6GLTv8weE8YH4BQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=Bel%C3%A9m+time
 And execute your code also. You'll get one hour difference. check it

Comment: Maybe daylight saving time makes the difference.

Comment: @vijayraman you can test here http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/zoneinfo?tz=America/Belem 
Also, you are asking for "America/Belem" whose timezone is -3, while timezone for "Brazil" that you are checking is -4

Comment: yes you're correct. How can we take the daylight in time calculation on above code!

Answer (score 0):

There are no future Daylight Saving Time rules for this time zone.
I'm using php's list of supported timezone, by using PHP's date_default_timezone_set, my only concern is the DST. I've found a method which works using PHP's DateTimezone class..

```
function timezoneDoesDST($tzId) {
    $tz = new DateTimeZone($tzId);
    $trans = $tz->getTransitions();
    return ((count($trans) && $trans[count($trans) - 1]['ts'] > time()));
}
```

The getTransitions() function gives you information about each time the offset changes for a timezone.

```
var_dump(timezoneDoesDST("America/Belem"));//Return bool(false);

var_dump(timezoneDoesDST("US/Pacific")); //Return bool(true);
var_dump(timezoneDoesDST("Europe/London")); //Return bool(true);
var_dump(timezoneDoesDST("America/Chicago")); //Return bool(true
```